# charge on product after purchage for free trial with Authorize.net CIM extension

Tags: magento, authorize.net

One of my client want following functionality with Authorize.net CIM :

> We would like to start offering Product for free for 30 days.  When
>   the clients signs up for their free trial of Product they would need
>   to give us their credit card number. We would charge them $0.01 to
>   make sure that the card was good. They would have 30days to cancel
>   their membership at no cost. At 31 days we would charge the card on
>   file $25.

I am not sure whats the term I should use for this, may be recurring or anything else.
Please help me how can I achieve this task?

Please suggest any extension that one can solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using CIM, but you will need to build your own scheduler to check daily if the correct number of days has passed and has not been cancelled. Also, if you create the payment profile using validationMode = liveMode, Authorize.Net will confirm that the card is valid as part of the creation process.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Really you feel my question, others are marking vote-down this. Now one more help I accepted from you. How can I achieve this checking process? I mean can you share with me any sample code or tutorial?